# Classic ASP: can't Return False from a function, I get a type mismatch error

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

```
' Determines if a file contains any of an array of lines.
' Case insensitive comparison.
Function DoesFileContainAnyLine(filename, lines)
    Dim fs
    set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fs.FileExists(filename) Then
        set f = fs.OpenTextFile(filename, 1, true) 
        Do Until f.AtEndOfStream 
            Dim line
            line = f.ReadLine
            For Each needle in lines
                if LCase(Trim(needle)) = LCase(Trim(line)) Then
                    return true
                end if
            Next
        Loop
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

I get a type mismatch error on the `Return False` line; why can't I return false from a function?

Comment: Because this is VBScript **not** JScript, use `DoesFileContainAnyLine = False`.

Comment: Oh, I see - I'm not all that familiar with VBscript and didn't realize I couldn't use the `return` keyword like in VB.NET - thanks!

Comment: It takes less than a minute to search, I just used `site:stackoverflow.com vbscript function` in [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNQ0OxPkzCvDJNGj2N1cHNWWrOE5Aw%3A1576858597310&ei=5fP8XanJEommgAbQxr6QBA&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+vbscript+function&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+vbscript+function&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1228.4099..4652...0.0..0.59.1084.20......0....1..gws-wiz.GM_kdD0wfGc&ved=0ahUKEwjpz7aE0MTmAhUJE8AKHVCjD0IQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)